# System.Windows.Data Error: 1 System.Windows.Data Error: 5

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, entity-framework-4, selecteditem

All,

I have a WPF app that has a DataGrid control bound to ItemsSource=MyContext.Entity1.Local (which is an ObservableCollection).
Inside of this app is a DataGridComboBoxColumn as follows:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="User"
                        SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Path=USR_ID, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=TBL_USR, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyEntity.TBL_USR, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Source={StaticResource VM}}"
                        SelectedValuePath="USR_ID"
                        DisplayMemberPath="USR_WINLOGON" />
```

My problem is that I get the following error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types MyContextType.TBL_USR' and 'System.String'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=TBL_USR; DataItem='Entity1Cl_4FDC0A147BE18671D96960BD8695EC4E3656B773570659474EE4FF228884E823' (HashCode=7143675); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'CellContent' (type 'String')
System.Windows.Data Error: 5 : Value produced by BindingExpression is not valid for target property.; Value='System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.TBL_USR30704B5EF5DAA11FBF2C9B305F529659FBCF422ED6696643EDB375A5D77F5A96' BindingExpression:Path=TBL_USR; DataItem='Entity1Cl_4FDC0A147BE18671D96960BD8695EC4E3656B773570659474EE4FF228884E823' (HashCode=7143675); target element is 'DataGridCell' (Name=''); target property is 'CellContent' (type 'String')
```

I figure it has something to do with DynamicProxies, but I can't figure out what's causing this (.Local?), and how to code around this (at least, not without using a TypeConverter and Reflection, yuck).

It's either that, or something to do with WPF misbehaving (but I can't find anywhere in the above markup where I'm trying to set my entity as a string).

So I ask, does anyone know how I can force Entity1.Local[n].TBL_USR to just be a TBL_USR, or if perhaps there's another way (without reflection) I could set my SelectedItemBinding?

Thanks.

I'm using EF 4.4 (Database First) and .Net 4.0.

Comment: Not everyone answer at once, eh?

Comment: I'd rather have an answer then a tumbleweed badge :(  I worked passed it, but didn't really ever resolve my issue.  I just hope it doesn't break sometime in the future.

Comment: I wonder if it's because I wasn't using local?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.  All of my bindings seem to work, since the data seems to get to my properties correctly, but those errors make me think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be due to the Mode=TwoWay and certain invisible bindings behind the scenes (for things like the clipboard).  I had tried using a string converter, but that had the odd effect of removing the display of the value when the column lost focus.  The answer to THAT issue is here:

[Why is my DataGridComboBoxColumn clearing its value when I navigate away from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504117/why-is-my-datagridcomboboxcolumn-clearing-its-value-when-i-navigate-away-from-it)

It turned out to be the answer to this issue as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Too bad I'm done with that project, but I'll remember this for next time :-)